# Ternary expression causing unnecessary copy. How to make this neat?

Tags: c++

I found using a profiler the source of an expensive copy. The code essentially looks like this.

```cpp
const auto& getDefaultValue();
auto processSomeParameters();

const auto& x = useDefault
    ? getDefaultValue()
    : processSomeParameters(...);
```

Intuitively, if `useDefault` is false, then the value returned by `processSomeParameters` should get its lifetime extended. If `useDefault` is true, we are already getting a `const&` from `getDefaultValue`.

Turns out, this will make a copy of whatever `getDefaultValue` returns. [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7365qdf7q).

Is there a neat way to transform this code to avoid the unnecessary copy?

Comment: Remove the reference `&` and use move semantics?

Comment: Is your condition known at compile-time or run-time?

Comment: Removing the `&` might work, but requires the type to have a default constructor (it doesn’t). The condition is not known at compile-time.

Comment: The problem is that the destruction of `x` would have to know how it was constructed (to know whether or not to destruct the lifetime-extended temporary). I think you can work around this with `std::optional<Value> processedValue; if (!useDefault) processedValue.emplace(processSomeParameters)); const auto& x = useDefault ? getDefaultValue() ? *processedValue;` The `std::optional` remembers the temporary that needs to be destructed.

Comment: In this case you might want to look into using smart pointers to avoid the copying costs. If the condition was known at compile-time you could do something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/9Yxxo81ss)

Comment: @RaymondChen This optional solution is pretty good.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean when you say that removing the `&` would require the type to have a default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I particularly recommend it, but you can do this:

```
const auto& x = useDefault
    ? getDefaultValue()
    : static_cast<decltype(getDefaultValue())>(processSomeParameters(...));
```

Here, both branches of the conditional expression will have the same type and value category (since the second branch is explicitly cast to `const T&`, where `T` is the type deduced for the placeholder) so no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion will need to be performed when the first branch is chosen.

Lifetime extension through complicated expressions like this is tricky, and it's easy for the next person who touches the code to mess it up and produce a dangling reference. That's why I don't recommend this approach. If you can factor whatever needs to be done with `x` into a separate function, the code will be much easier to understand and harder to mess up:

```
if (useDefault) {
    f(getDefaultValue());
} else {
    f(processSomeParameters());
}
```